# classloader policy for single jars in various application servers?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere, weblogic

We regularly have problems with old jars residing in the app-servers but newer jars deployed in our ears. Appserver chooses to load old jar and application throws "UnsupportedMethod" Exceptions or similar.

**For main application servers (websphere, jboss, weblogic ...), how can I configure classloader policy for single jars?**

( e.g. in wwebsphere there is class-loading policy "parent-first / application-first" but this is global for the application and will change behavior for many many jars, while the issue is only with one single jar..., for weblogic there is weblogic-application.xml IIRC etcpp. )

This is intended as a collection call, please describe the correct way to configure this in the **application server of your choice** (not only websphere please).

Comment: I still miss answers for other application servers ...

Answer (score 1):

In WAS there is no way to control classloading on JAR level. I don't quite understand why you can't use Parent Last policy since it is natural and safe way to avoid unwanted dependencies.

If you still need to handle dependencies on JAR level you might find [Web Application Bundles](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.osgi.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ca_wab.html) useful. This is based on OSGi which offers completely different classloading model.

Comment: with hundreds of jars delivered, we could not predict the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

So you can only control classloading on a specific classloader. In websphere there is a feature that makes it possible to create your own custom classloader with a specified "delegation mode" or classloader policy, i.e. parent last or parent first. So your option is to create a custom classloader which has your dependent jar-file/s in it and the specify the classloader policy to "parent last" for the classloader.

Another option is the WAR classloader policy, that is if the dependecy comes from a particular webmodule. Then you have to put your jar/s into the web-inf/lib in that WAR.

Note that there will still be a risk since there will be multiple versions of the "same" classes residing in the same JVM heap space, those loaded by the Websphere classloaders and those loaded by your custom classloader. This means that there is a risk for class version collisions where your code will suffer from ClassCastExceptions and LinkageErrors.

For more information read here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fttrb_classload_viewer.html

Comment: but the risk will only affect my application right? because roumor has it that changing the policy will confuse other apps, e.g. admin-console.

Answer (score 1):

The middle ground for individual jars is to put them into a websphere "shared library" which will be searched before the products own jars without changing to parent-last for the entire module.

Here is a link to education on "isolated" shared libraries, an optional further setting for shared libraries:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/Administration/WASv7_IsolatedSharedLibraries/player.html